# Failed to build rtabmap_ros in my catkin_ws

Tags: c++, ros, vtk

I tried to build [rtabmap_ros](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros) in my `catkin_ws` and I got this error:

```
  user@user-desktop:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
    Base path: /home/user/catkin_ws
    Source space: /home/user/catkin_ws/src
    Build space: /home/user/catkin_ws/build
    Devel space: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel
    Install space: /home/user/catkin_ws/install
    ####
    #### Running command: "cmake /home/user/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/user/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/user/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/user/catkin_ws/build"
    ####
    -- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel
    -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/melodic
    -- This workspace overlays: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/melodic
    -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.17", minimum required is "2") 
    -- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2
    -- Using Debian Python package layout
    -- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
    -- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
    -- Call enable_testing()
    -- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/user/catkin_ws/build/test_results
    -- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
    -- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
    -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.17") 
    -- Looking for pthread.h
    -- Looking for pthread.h - found
    -- Looking for pthread_create
    -- Looking for pthread_create - not found
    -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
    -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
    -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
    -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
    -- Found Threads: TRUE  
    -- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
    -- catkin 0.7.29
    -- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
    -- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
    -- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    -- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
    -- ~~  - rtabmap_ros
    -- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    -- +++ processing catkin package: 'rtabmap_ros'
    -- ==> add_subdirectory(rtabmap_ros)
    -- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
    CMake Warning at rtabmap_ros/CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package):
      By not providing "Findfiducial_msgs.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
      project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
      "fiducial_msgs", but CMake did not find one.
    
      Could not find a package configuration file provided by "fiducial_msgs"
      with any of the following names:
    
        fiducial_msgsConfig.cmake
        fiducial_msgs-config.cmake
    
      Add the installation prefix of "fiducial_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
      "fiducial_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
      "fiducial_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
      has been installed.
    
    
    -- Found RTABMap: /opt/ros/melodic/lib/librtabmap_core.so;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/librtabmap_utilite.so;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/librtabmap_gui.so;/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libg2o_core.so;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libg2o_types_slam2d.so;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libg2o_types_slam3d.so;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libg2o_types_sba.so;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libg2o_stuff.so;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libg2o_solver_csparse.so;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libg2o_csparse_extension.so;/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcxsparse.so;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libg2o_solver_cholmod.so;/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcholmod.so;/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libfreenect.so;/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libfreenect_sync.so;/usr/lib/libOpenNI2.so;/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdc1394.so;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/liboctomap.so;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/liboctomath.so (Required is at least version "0.20.18") 
    -- Checking for module 'eigen3'
    --   Found eigen3, version 3.3.4
    -- Found eigen: /usr/include/eigen3  
    -- Checking for module 'libopenni'
    --   Found libopenni, version 1.5.4.0
    -- Found openni: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so  
    -- The imported target "vtkGUISupportQt" references the file
       "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvtkGUISupportQt-6.3.so.6.3.0"
    but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
    * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
    * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
    * The installation package was faulty and contained
       "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
    but not all the files it references.
    
    -- The imported target "vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL" references the file
       "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvtkGUISupportQtOpenGL-6.3.so.6.3.0"
    but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
    * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
    * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
    * The installation package was faulty and contained
       "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
    but not all the files it references.
    
    -- The imported target "vtkGUISupportQtSQL" references the file
       "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvtkGUISupportQtSQL-6.3.so.6.3.0"
    but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
    * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
    * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
    * The installation package was faulty and contained
       "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
    but not all the files it references.
    
    -- The imported target "vtkViewsQt" references the file
       "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsQt-6.3.so.6.3.0"
    but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
    * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
    * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
    * The installation package was faulty and contained
       "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
    but not all the files it references.
    
    -- The imported target "vtkGUISupportQtWebkit" references the file
       "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvtkGUISupportQtWebkit-6.3.so.6.3.0"
    but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
    * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
    * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
    * The installation package was faulty and contained
       "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
    but not all the files it references.
    
    -- The imported target "vtkRenderingQt" references the file
       "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingQt-6.3.so.6.3.0"
    but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
    * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
    * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
    * The installation package was faulty and contained
       "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
    but not all the files it references.
    
    -- The imported target "vtkRenderingQtTCL" references the file
       "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingQtTCL-6.3.so.6.3.0"
    but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
    * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
    * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
    * The installation package was faulty and contained
       "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
    but not all the files it references.
    
    -- The imported target "vtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets" references the file
       "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.so"
    but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
    * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
    * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
    * The installation package was faulty and contained
       "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
    but not all the files it references.
    
    -- The imported target "vtk" references the file
       "/usr/bin/vtk"
    but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
    * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
    * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
    * The installation package was faulty and contained
       "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
    but not all the files it references.
    
    -- The imported target "vtkRenderingQtPythonD" references the file
       "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingQtPython27D-6.3.so.6.3.0"
    but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
    * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
    * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
    * The installation package was faulty and contained
       "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
    but not all the files it references.
    
    -- Found libusb-1.0: /usr/include  
    -- Checking for module 'flann'
    --   Found flann, version 1.9.1
    -- Found Flann: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libflann_cpp_s.a  
    -- Found qhull: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libqhull.so  
    -- Found PCL_COMMON: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so  
    -- Found PCL_OCTREE: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcl_octree.so  
    -- Found PCL_IO: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcl_io.so  
    -- Found PCL_KDTREE: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcl_kdtree.so  
    -- Found PCL_SEARCH: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcl_search.so  
    -- Found PCL_SURFACE: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcl_surface.so  
    -- Found PCL_FILTERS: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcl_filters.so  
    -- Found PCL_2D: /usr/include/pcl-1.8  
    -- Found PCL_FEATURES: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcl_features.so  
    -- Found PCL_REGISTRATION: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcl_registration.so  
    -- Found PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcl_sample_consensus.so  
    -- Found PCL_GEOMETRY: /usr/include/pcl-1.8  
    -- Found PCL_ML: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcl_ml.so  
    -- Found PCL_SEGMENTATION: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcl_segmentation.so  
    -- Found PCL_VISUALIZATION: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcl_visualization.so  
    -- RTABMAP_SYNC_MULTI_RGBD = OFF
    -- RTABMAP_SYNC_USER_DATA  = OFF
    -- rtabmap_ros: 18 messages, 16 services
    -- WITH octomap_msgs
    -- WITH apriltag_ros
    -- WITH find_object_2d
    -- checking for module 'OGRE'
    --   found OGRE, version 1.9.0
    -- WITH rviz
    -- WITH costmap_2d
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /home/user/catkin_ws/build
    ####
    #### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/user/catkin_ws/build"
    ####
    Scanning dependencies of target rtabmap_costmap_plugins
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_Point2f
    Scanning dependencies of target rtabmap_point_cloud_assembler
    Scanning dependencies of target rtabmap_pointcloud_to_depthimage
    make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvtkGUISupportQtOpenGL-6.3.so.6.3.0', needed by '/home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rtabmap_ros/point_cloud_assembler'.  Stop.
    make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    [  0%] Building CXX object rtabmap_ros/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_point_cloud_assembler.dir/src/PointCloudAssemblerNode.cpp.o
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_Point2f
    make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvtkGUISupportQtOpenGL-6.3.so.6.3.0', needed by '/home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rtabmap_ros/pointcloud_to_depthimage'.  Stop.
    make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    [  0%] Building CXX object rtabmap_ros/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_pointcloud_to_depthimage.dir/src/PointCloudToDepthImageNode.cpp.o
    [  0%] Building CXX object rtabmap_ros/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_costmap_plugins.dir/src/costmap_2d/static_layer.cpp.o
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_NodeData
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_NodeData
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_GetMap
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_GetMap
    Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
    [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
    Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
    [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_Info
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_Info
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_GetPlan
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_GetPlan
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_MapGraph
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_MapGraph
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_RemoveLabel
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_RemoveLabel
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_GetNodesInRadius
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_GetNodesInRadius
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_SetLabel
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_SetLabel
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_ScanDescriptor
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_ScanDescriptor
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_MapData
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_MapData
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_Path
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_Path
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_PublishMap
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_PublishMap
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_AddLink
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_AddLink
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_DetectMoreLoopClosures
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_DetectMoreLoopClosures
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_GPS
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_GPS
    Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
    [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_KeyPoint
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_KeyPoint
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_OdomInfo
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_OdomInfo
    Scanning dependencies of target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_RGBDImages
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:706: recipe for target 'rtabmap_ros/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_point_cloud_assembler.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [rtabmap_ros/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_point_cloud_assembler.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    [  0%] Built target _rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_RGBDImages
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:743: recipe for target 'rtabmap_ros/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_pointcloud_to_depthimage.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [rtabmap_ros/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_pointcloud_to_depthimage.dir/all] Error 2
    [  0%] Linking CXX shared library /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/librtabmap_costmap_plugins.so
    [  0%] Built target rtabmap_costmap_plugins
    Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

I also have issues installing this particular library `libvtkGUISupportQtOpenGL-6.3.so.6.3.0`.

Comment: Like your error message says: "libvtkGUISupportQt (...) was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location, An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully, or The installation package was faulty". Check your system, maybe clean VTK package, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to install [fiducial_msgs](https://wiki.ros.org/fiducial_msgs):

```
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-fiducial-msgs
```